# Need help on uniqid

Tags: php

So I wrote this function to generate a unique 8 digit code which works great. Basically someone is going to choose how many of these codes are going to be generated. 1, 10, 50, 100 etc. What I need is how to take this function and whatever value they chose on the form and generate that amount of unique id's.

This is Written in PHP

```
<? function generate_coupon_code () {   
    $numbers = uniqid(); 
    $coupon_code = substr($numbers, -8);
    return $coupon_code; 
} 

echo generate_coupon_code();
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You just want to call your function multiple times? This returns the chosen number of codes in an array.

```
function generate_multiple_codes ($number_of_codes)
{
  $codes = array ();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_codes; $i++)
  {
    $codes[] = generate_coupon_code ();
  }
  return $codes;
}
```